# Get the ID of a new Feature after adding to MapView via Editor Widget

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I'm pretty new to ArcGIS so pardon my ignorance: how can I get the ID of a newly added Feature of a MapView?

Using the ArcGIS JavaScript SDK, I have a MapView defined as follows:

```
var portalItem = new PortalItem({
    id: appId
})

map = new WebMap({
    portalItem: portalItem
})
mapView = new MapView({
    container: 'composableEsriMap',
    map,
    ui: {
        components: []
    }
})
```

Within this MapView I want users to be able to add a new Feature, so I use the Editor Widget which I define as follows:

```
const addEditor = () => {

    const featureLayer = map.layers.find(layer => layer.type === 'feature')

    const editor = new Editor({

        view: mapView,

        allowedWorkflows: 'create',

        layerInfos: [

            {

                layer: new FeatureLayer({

                    url: --URL REDACTED--

                })

            }

        ]

    })

    editor.on('create', (e: any) => {

        console.log('FEATURE ADDED: ', e.features[0])

    })

    mapView.ui.add(editor, 'top-right')
}
```

This adds the feature just fine, but I need to store the ID of the new feature in my database, so how can I get the ID of the new feature programmatically? I have tried a few different things, but the approach I have above creates an event handler for the "create" method of the Editor. The issue is that handler is never triggered--probably because the Editor doesn't even have such an event. How should I be going about this?

Comment: I think the issue is that the map gets my layer from the app, so when I `new FeatureLayer(url)` this is a separate layer that I am listening to that isn't being interacted with, and that is why my handler isn't triggered even when I follow the example found here https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#event-edits If that is the issue, how can I get a reference to the FeatureLayer that is already in the map?

Comment: Use the `allLayers` property of the map to obtain the `FeatureLayer` ([ArcGIS API - Map all layers](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html#allLayers))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving that is to listen for `FeatureLayer` `applyEdits` method ([ArcGIS API - FeatureLayer applyEdits](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#applyEdits)), witch is the method used by the widget in order to make the edits. Here is simple sample I put for you,

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Edit features with the Editor widget | Sample | ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript 4.27</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/"></script>

  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

  </style>

  <script>
    require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Editor"
      ], (
        Map,
        MapView,
        FeatureLayer,
        Editor
      ) => {

        const featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
            url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/El_Paso_Recreation_AttributeEditsOnly/FeatureServer/1"
        });

        // Create a map from the referenced webmap item id
        const map = new Map({
            basemap: "topo-vector"
        });

        map.add(featureLayer);

        const view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map
        });

        view.when(() => {
          const editor = new Editor({
            view: view
          });
          view.ui.add(editor, "top-right");
        });

        featureLayer.on("apply-edits", f => {
            f.result.then(edits => console.log(edits));
        });
      });
  </script>
</head>
```

You will notice that the example is printing in console the inputs and outputs on the call to the function. In your case you will have to check the property `addFeatureResults`.

Comment: This isn't working for me, unfortunately. I'm using typescript and the only values it allows for `featureLayer.on()` are 'edits', 'layerview-create', 'layerview-create-error', 'layerview-destroy', & 'refresh'. I tried with 'edits', but the handler is never reached. I also ignored typescript and used 'apply-edits' like you say, same result. I am now adding the event listener to the featureLayer before I add it to the editor. I just found this documenation https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#event-edits

Comment: What version of the library are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 4.27.6 of the @arcgis/core npm package

Comment: Okay, the takeaway was that I needed to defined my editor within view.when(). Thanks!